# Calling another PL/SQL procedure within a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, procedures

I'm new to PL/SQL & would greatly appreciate help in this. I've created a procedure to copy contracts. Now I want to call another procedure from within this procedure which shall copy all the programs related to the contract I'm copying. One contract can have multiple programs.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pls show your code

Comment: Read about private procedures in oracle. You will find the solution.

Comment: There's no difference whether you call a procedure from within a procedure or from a pl/sql block; if you can call it from a block, you can call it from a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You cal call another procedure in another package by using `PackageName.ProcedureName(vcParameters => 'InputParameter1');` 
If the procedure is in the same package you could do it without the `PackageName`, so just `ProcedureName(vcParameters => 'InputParameter1');`

Answer (score 0):

You call a procedure by simply putting its name and parameters in your code, e.g.

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Demo');
end;
```

or within a procedure,

```
create or replace procedure demo
as
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Demo');
end;
```

I have used `dbms_output.put_line` as an example of a procedure, but obviously any other procedure would be called the same way:

```
begin
    foo;
    bar(1);
    demo(true, 'Bananas', date '2018-01-01');
end;
```

For some reason, many beginners are tempted to add `exec` before the procedure call. I don't know where that comes from because PL/SQL has no such keyword. Possibly they are thinking of the SQL*Plus [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/EXECUTE.html) command, which can be abbreviated to `exec`. However, SQL*Plus is a separate command line utility with its own commands that have nothing to do with the PL/SQL language.