# can we call stored procedure inside stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Please explain this one, can we call stored procedure inside stored procedure ?

Comment: This seems to come up a lot, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38842882/230471 I wonder if there is any programming language that does not allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not. Suppose there are two procedures, `proc_a` and `proc_b`.

```
create or replace procedure proc_a is
begin
  proc_b;          --> this is how you call proc_b from proc_a
end;
/
```